# Image alignment in dynamic layout

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I'm currently working on a blog layout and have hit a wall trying to figure out the best way to achieve the image alignment.

Each blog post has two images; a 'background' image set to .5 opacity and second 'top' image set to 1 opacity. The background image needs to sit under the top image.

So far I have got the layout to this point here http://dev.thefold.com.au/sandbox/staggered/portfolio-2-col.html but cannot figure out how to get the background image under the top image, leaving a 160px distance between the top image and the background image - in a way that can accommodate undetermined image heights. This html/css will eventually be used in a Wordpress theme so the solution needs to accommodate user added images that will have different heights.

An image of what I am trying to achieve is here http://dev.thefold.com.au/sandbox/staggered/reworked.png

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Prefer not to if at all possible, but Javascript will be running on the page.

Comment: The background image will be a completely different image. Both the top and background image will have an undetermined (auto) height. I was hoping I could somehow anchor the bottom of the background image 160px down from the bottom of the top image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, see here:

```css
.bk-effect {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.bk-effect img:first-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.bk-effect img:last-child {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: -160px; /* How much down of the original image */
  right: -150px;  /* How much right of the original image */
}
```

```html
<div class="bk-effect">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/000">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x300/000">
</div>
```

To reuse it:

- Copy the CSS over
- Make a `div` with the class `bk-effect`
- The first image used as the main image
- The last image will be used as the background image

Currently, the images will be offset by `160px` down and `150px` to the right. You can change these values by altering the relevant line below.

Note: I added `font-size: 0; line-height: 0;` to remove any space under the image. This allows the offset to be exact, but it also means that no text will display inside the `.bk-effect` element.

For the link provided, change the code to:

```
.img-portfolio > a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-right: 50px;   /* How much right of the original image */
  padding-bottom:160px; /* How much down of the original image */
  width: 85%; /* Move the 85% to here */
}

.img-portfolio > a img:first-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 100%; /* Remove the 85% here and move it up */
}

.img-portfolio > a img:last-child {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Note: You can't change the width of the main image, of the offset on the right side is going to be off. Instead, change the width of the `a` link.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll see if I can incorporate that into the layout here http://dev.thefold.com.au/sandbox/staggered/portfolio-2-col.html

Comment: Thanks Chris. I reworked what you first suggested into my layout here http://dev.thefold.com.au/sandbox/staggered-2/portfolio-2-col.html and it seems to be working ok. I have a percentage width on the images which I will need for when it is implemented in the Wordpress theme. Can you see any issues with this solution?

Comment: The percentage width should be okay, but it will not always result in having an exact offset. Looks good!